# Performance - should I use both Arrays and Objects for huge list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object

Till now, my server has handled huge **arrays** of **entities**.

Mainly, it does a **for loop** *x times per second* on **entities**, checking if one entity is in the scope of an other entity (each entity has an array **entitiesInScope**) by doing **entitiesInScope.indexOf(entity)**, and that's the biggest cost of my program.

```
for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {
    var entity = entities[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < entities.length; j++) {
        var checkEntity = entities[j];
        var idx = entity.entitiesInScope.indexOf(checkEntity);
        if (idx >= 0) {
            if (!check(checkEntity.state, entity.state)) {
                entity.removeEntityInScope(idx);
                //... remove: send checkEntity.id
            } 
        } else {
            if (check(checkEntity.state, entity.state)) {
                entity.addEntityInScope(checkEntity);
                //... add: send checkEntity.id, checkEntity.state
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*(I've optimized it by not doing the second loop on **all** the entities, but that's not the point)*

However, I've seen that Object's **hasOwnProperty** is [much faster](https://jsperf.com/object-hasownproperty-vs-array-indexof/2) than indexOf. On the other side, I also do a lot of push and splice. So if I add an Object of entities, I should use delete (perf?) too.

Should I:

-add an object with id entity key, to use hasOwnProperty(entity.id), and then allow to use indexOf if true?

-add an object with entity key, to use hasOwnProperty(entity.id) (memory wasting)?

-continue with arrays

Comment: Why don´t you just traverse the entitiesInScope array instead of the second loop?

Comment: Or perhaps a Map? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map )

Comment: @juvian in fact, there is a physics loop that updates the state of the entities (position,...), and there is a broadcast loop (previous code) where the entitiesInScope are updated (add/remove) for each entity, by doing some checks.

Comment: @Miyud what do need the index for? If it´s just to check existance using an object is much better

Comment: @juvian to remove from entitiesInScope if it is in scope and if the checks are negative

Comment: @Miyud in that case using an object instead of array and using hasOwnProperty + delete would be much more efficient. But just traversing entitiesInScope is even better... (you would need to traverse it backwards to remove without messing up indexes)

Comment: @juvian ok thanks. I had doubt about delete performance. Also, looping over an array is more efficient than looping over an object. Overall, I should use both (memory loss but time gain), isn't it ?

Comment: @Miyud delete works better for object than array. Not sure if looping is slower but there shouldn´t be much difference. I believe you can just use arrays and remove your second loop, but would need to view a bit more of what you do in your second loop if you want me to show how

Comment: @juvian I've added details to the previous code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134106/discussion-between-juvian-and-miyud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to iterate over entitiesInScope to update or remove the entities there, as you already know the indexes that way and if you traverse it backwards you can remove the items without messing up indexes.

As for adding the missing entities, I would mark the ones already on entitiesInScope in an object for fast lookup and then iterate over entities and add the missing ones. The code would be something similar to this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {
    var entity = entities[i];
    var alreadyInScope = {}

    for (var j = entity.entitiesInScope.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        var checkEntity = entity.entitiesInScope[j];

        if (!check(checkEntity.state, entity.state)) {
           var id = entity.entitiesInScope.splice(j, 1).id
        } else {
            alreadyInScope[checkEntity.id] = true;
        }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < entities.length; j++) {
        if (alreadyInScope.hasOwnProperty(entities[j].id) == false) {
            entity.entitiesInScope.push(entities[j])
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you mean splice(-1,1) to delete last element. Btw, is there a performance difference with forward splice(j,1), or just for user convenience ?

Comment: @Miyud my mistake, splice(j, 1) is the right option

Comment: @Miyud if you have many entities in alreadyInScope and you usually remove more than 10, it would probably be more efficient to add the ones that you will not remove to a temporary array and at the end of the loop replace alreadyInScope with the temporary array